# quartz 2.2 can't set the instanceName

Tags: quartz-scheduler

My applications need use the cluster mode. It's my properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime=1 
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 15000
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=testSchedule
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy=false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction=false
org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdown=true
org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdownWithWait=true 
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true
```

but in the table qrtz_fired_triggers.INSTANCE_NAME=US2047839W11427446115791. I think it's not the correct instanceName ( ----> testSchedule)

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=testSchedule
```

Is there any thing wrong with our setup (spring3.2.4+quartz2.2)??

Comment: instanceId corresponds to the qrtz_fired_triggers.INSTANCE_NAME.
instanceName corresponds to the column SCHED_NAME exist in tables  t_opt_qrtz_fired_triggers, t_opt_qrtz_job_details, t_opt_qrtz_locks, It's just save the default value 'quartzScheduler' not the 'testSchedule'